# div is pushed by another div when toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having somewhat two navigation bars right here. When I click on the menu-btn, the sidebar will slide in. But somehow the sidebar pushes the menu-bar downwards which I do not understand why. How do I make the sidebar stop pushing the menu-bar. Any tips will be appreciated.

```js
    function main(){
            $(".menu-bar").hide();
            $(".menu-bar").fadeIn(300);
            $(".sidebar").hide();
            $(".dropdown-content").hide();

            $(".menu-btn").on('click',function(){
                $(".sidebar").animate({width:'toggle'});
                
            });
            $(".close-btn").on('click',function(){
                $(".sidebar").animate({width:'toggle'});
            });

            $(".login").on('click',function(){
                $(".dropdown-content").animate({width:'toggle'});
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(main)
```

```css
   .sidebar{
    display:none;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#005777;
    z-index:1;
    padding-top:60px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    
    }
    .brand{
    font-family:ParmaPetit;
    font-size:50px;
    }
    .sidebar a, .login{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    display:block;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;

    }
    .close-btn{
    position:relative;
    font-size:40px;
    float:right;
    bottom:50px;
    right:10px;
    color:white;
    }
    .sidebar a:hover, .login:hover, .close-btn:hover, .menu-btn:hover{
    color:#01af55;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:0.3s;
    }
    .dropdown-content{
    background-color:#111111;
    position:relative;
    left:250px;
    bottom:29px;
    }
    .menu-bar{
    background-color:#005777;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:top;
    }
    .menu-btn{
    font-size:40px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
        <a href="#" class="brand" style="padding-bottom:50px;font-size:40px;">Airline Intel</a>
        <a href="#">Book Flight</a>
        <a href="#">Book Hotel</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <span class="login">Sign In &#x27A4;</span>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Admin</a>
                <a href="#">User</a>
                <a href="#">Register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-bar" id="collapse">
        <span class="menu-btn">&#9776;</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: In your HTML you have SIDEBAR placed before MENU, so when you show it, it will push the menu down. The page is doing exactly what you have told it to. If you want the sidebar to slide over the page/menu, you should look to give it `position:absolute`. https://jsfiddle.net/yek2z6e9/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a `position : absolute;` to the sidebar class should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```js
function main(){
            $(".menu-bar").hide();
            $(".menu-bar").fadeIn(300);
            $(".sidebar").hide();
            $(".dropdown-content").hide();

            $(".menu-btn").on('click',function(){
              $('#collapse').hide();
                $(".sidebar").animate({width:'toggle'});
                
            });
            $(".close-btn").on('click',function(){
            $('#collapse').show();
                $(".sidebar").animate({width:'toggle'});
            });

            $(".login").on('click',function(){
                $(".dropdown-content").animate({width:'toggle'});
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(main)
```

```css
.sidebar{
    display:none;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#005777;
    z-index:1;
    padding-top:60px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    
    }
    .brand{
    font-family:ParmaPetit;
    font-size:50px;
    }
    .sidebar a, .login{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    display:block;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;

    }
    .close-btn{
    position:relative;
    font-size:40px;
    float:right;
    bottom:50px;
    right:10px;
    color:white;
    }
    .sidebar a:hover, .login:hover, .close-btn:hover, .menu-btn:hover{
    color:#01af55;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:0.3s;
    }
    .dropdown-content{
    background-color:#111111;
    position:relative;
    left:250px;
    bottom:29px;
    }
    .menu-bar{
    background-color:#005777;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:top;
    }
    .menu-btn{
    font-size:40px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
        <a href="#" class="brand" style="padding-bottom:50px;font-size:40px;">Airline Intel</a>
        <a href="#">Book Flight</a>
        <a href="#">Book Hotel</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <span class="login">Sign In &#x27A4;</span>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Admin</a>
                <a href="#">User</a>
                <a href="#">Register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-bar" id="collapse">
        <span class="menu-btn">&#9776;</span>
    </div>
```

you need to hide menu button when you clicked it. and show when you click in close button.

Comment: I doubt hiding it completely is the desired result.